# How to make the StackPanel or DockPanel stretch to fit their containers in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a `Grid` as a root container with two columns defined (There's only one row).
The first column has flexible width and second column has 300px fixed width.
Next, I have placed a `ListBox` inside the second column to stretch both horizontally and vertically, i.e. to fill the entire second column.
Lastly, I have defined an Items Template for the `ListBox` to be a vertically oriented `StackPanel`, with one `DockPanel` and a couple of `TextBlock`s inside.

```
<!-- Data template for ListBox -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Track}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <DockPanel>
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="Now playing" />
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="Time remaining" />
    </DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

...

<ListBox 
  Grid.Column="1" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I make the `StackPanel` fill the entire width of the `ListBox`? Right now, it only takes enough space to accomodate the `DockPanel` and the `TextBlock`s inside. It won't fit the width of the `ListBox` or `ListBoxItem`.
2. Next, how do I make the `DockPanel` fill the entire width of the `StackPanel`, i.e. its parent? What happens right now is that even if the width of the `TextBlock`s in the `StackPanel` exceed the width of the `DockPanel`, it won't stretch to match their width.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make the Content of every `ListBoxItem` stretch by setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` in the ItemContainerStyle

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you Meleak. That solves the first question. Do you know how to make the `DockPanel` stretch to fit the width of the `StackPanel`?

Comment: @Boris: I think it already does. I pasted your DataTemplate into a sample app and checked it with Snoop and it seems to stretch. Try setting a Background for the `DockPanel` like `<DockPanel Background="Red">`. Does it stretch? Your problem may be that the `TextBlock` is stretching as well, try to set `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` for your second `TextBlock`

Comment: I just realized that the `DockPanel` won't stretch unless I have an Element that will take the central area of the panel. That's kind of ridiculous to me, as in my case I only have left and right elements. Do you know a workaround to this (other than placing a dummy element in the `DockPanel`'s central area), or do you have any other recommendations on what should I use instead of the `DockPanel` to achieve the same effect? Thanks.

Comment: My bad, your trick to set `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` solves the issue. Thanks a bunch for helping me out. Solved!