# First Element in list box item is overlapping the second element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Listbox and each listbox item contain a DockPanel with two elements TextBlock and a Label. Following is the xaml Code -

```
        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
           <ListBoxItem>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Ted its so wonderfull I am gere asdf asdf asdf adsf asdf asdf asdfasf asfd asf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdasfd asf " TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                <Label Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
            </DockPanel>                
        </ListBoxItem>

        <ListBoxItem>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Ted its so wonderfull Ted its so wonderfull I am gere asdf asdf asdf adsf asdf asdf asdfasf asfd asf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdasfd asf" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                <Label Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
            </DockPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

So I was expecting a window where each row will have two elements first coloumn is the text block and the next one is a label. I added the HorizonatalContentAlignment=stretch and HorizontalAlignment=Right for labels for when user resize the window the label should go to the right end.

But the issue I am facing with the above code is when I resize the window and when the text block start to wrap, Textblock is hiding/overlapping the Label element. In some case the label is completely hidden, when a word in the text block perfectly align with the right end of the window, or is partially hidden ?

Why the second element is getting overlapped or hidden ?  I want to show the click me label always, How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Grid. The first column uses all available space, where the second column reserves space for the 'click' label.

```
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Ted its so wonderfull I am gere asdf asdf asdf adsf asdf asdf asdfasf asfd asf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdasfd asf " TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </ListBoxItem>
```

The image below shows the grid compared to the dock approach.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just to point out that in **other scenarios** like *unknown number of Elements* to be added to a `ListBoxItem` content for example, using a `DockPanel` is not that bad.

Example :

- First item in the `ListBox`, I want a `Text` and a `Label`.
- Secund item, I want a `Text`, a `Label` **and a `Button`**.
- and so on...

With a `Grid`, it won't work unless you add a lot of things (either using ContentTemplate and Bindings or even Code behind) and that's where a `DockPanel` is usefull.

What's wrong in your approach is that you've put the `TextBlock` **before** the `Label`. In DockPanel, order matters and first item takes precedence over the secund, the secund over the third... and if a previous item has taken all the remaining space (which your TextBlock did with its very long `Text` value) then any other following item will not be drawn as expected.

And don't forget to specify the `Docking` mode.

So, just for clarification, there's nothing wrong using a DockPanel here, but items order matters.

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <DockPanel>
            <!-- Declare your Label first and dock it to the right -->
            <Label 
                DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            <TextBlock 
                Text="Ted its so wonderfull I am gere asdf asdf asdf adsf asdf asdf asdfasf asfd asf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdasfd asf " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </DockPanel>                
    </ListBoxItem>

    <!-- ... -->

</ListBox>
```

Some UIElements like Label doesn't (really) require `HorizontalAlignment` when they are `Left/Right` docked inside a DockPanel. In that case, **only** the `VerticalAlignment` matters.

**Rule is :**

- Remember that a DockPanel allocates a **rectangular** area for each item.
- Items get that allocated area in order.
- DockPanel default the docking to the left.
- DockPanel better works with a list of items occupying a small area that are declared **first** and docked accordingly, then a **last** item of variable size that will fill the remaining space if available.
- DockPanel will always try to show at least a small piece of every item when the available area is not sufficiently wide (so carefully add constrains when you want an item to remain fully visible, like putting the DockPanel **inside** a Grid Column or Row ;) )

> In the end, this is an answer that explains why the Label is
>   overlapped by the TextBlock – for other readers wanting to master a
>   DockPanel.
>
> But yeah, when I already know how many items I'm going to have in a
>   container, I'll use a Grid, 99% of the time, because I can bind Row
>   and Columns size directly, while with a DockPanel, StackPanel, etc, I
>   would have to reference each contained item one by one.
>
> I do agree with the accepted answer :)

Comment: Nice answer. Upvoted myself. I've tried to fix the users problem however this answer tries to explain how and why.

Comment: Thanks. :) Oh! One other thing that could play a role in a combination `ListBoxItem+Grid` or `ListBoxItem+DockPanel`, with a docking to the right : adding a style setter to `HorizontalContentAlignment` Property of child `ListBoxItem` from `ListBox` declaration as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5079743/2410892). ListBoxItem has a container that don't automatically stretches to fill all the space, so docking to the right doesn't really works if the contained content is not wide enough. :) Not directly involved here, but related. Hope that save some minutes for anyone experiencing this.